# Storing refresh tokens in a database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

I am trying to build an API on ASP.NET Core 5. My authorization is implemented using JWT and refresh tokens.


As I understood, when the user **registers**, we provide him an access token (that expires in ~5 minutes, usually) and a refresh token (long-lasting one). We **store** refresh tokens in our database.


My struggle comes into play with **login** requests. In all of the tutorials we must decalre a method with the name like "GenerateAuthResultAsync()" that gets called on registration and on login and **writes** a refresh token object data to our DB. As a result, on login a new refresh token gets generated, as well as on registration. It is possible, that there would be 2 valid refresh tokens available for a single user. Is it normal?

Comment: Unless you want the user to only login on a single computer at a time (or multiple computers in 5-mintue intervals) then that's normal. We have a Angular-based web app, native Android app, and native iOS app. A single user could have multiple smartphone devices, or open the application in multiple browsers or on multiple computers. Clearly each would need its own refresh token to maintain its own session. Now, you could potentially invalidate older refresh tokens from the same client (if you're able to tell that) for added security.

Comment: @Llama, well, then, how can I ensure, that a user has only a single refresh token for every device he uses?

Comment: JWT usually used when you don't want to store anything in database, and just use cookies as storage. For example, if you have high-load frontend where it is critical. If you store JWT in database - you better switch to sessions, but bear in mind it will become main reason for DDoS and performance issues.

Comment: @eocorn, JWT is stored in user's browser local storage. Refresh token has nothing to do with JWT at all. It is simply a GUID in my case.